# Is it possible to screencast from android tablet to smartboard or another android tablet

Tags: android, android-studio, screencast

I want to develop an application which live-screencast from android tablet to smartboard or another android tablet.
 
Connection type between two devices should be wireless internet connection without using usb and bluetooth. I use android studio.
 
Is it possible to implement it? Could you suggest me some ways or libraries to do it?
I hope I make myself clear.
Any help is apreciated.
Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

Our devices support v4. 
 
In addition to the information above, I need an rdp library or api to do it.

Comment: This can be done with wifi..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android v5.0 lollipop is the first to provide some API for this. See the following links:

[Media projection API overview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/package-summary.html)

[The screen grabber function](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjection.html#createVirtualDisplay%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20android.view.Surface,%20android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay.Callback,%20android.os.Handler%29)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I forgot to say that our devices don't support v5. Do you know rdp (remote desktop protocol) library or api supporting v4?

Comment: Android v4 or earlier has no API for grabbing screen. AFAIK you can only grab screen by hacking / accessing frame buffer directly. It's also different for each device. That's why there are no RDP servers for Android.